# about fmp4 encoding , how to fill the mdat box wit H264 frame?

Tags: c, mp4, h.264, fmp4

I used C language to encode H264 frames (just have I/P frame) into fmp4 files. When I fill the mdat box, I don't know how to fill the frame data.
Is (I/P)frame data filled directly?
Do the first 4 bytes need to be filled with frame length?

I tried to use FFMPG to encode fmp4 file, and found that the data in mdat box was completely different from the original I/P frame data.
Is it coded again?
Can I directly fill the data of I/P frame into mdat box?

Comment: please add your code which you tried till now.

Comment: The code is messy and inconvenient to display, just tell me the way of thinking, and then I will debug, thank you very much!

Comment: Create a [mcve] please. If you follow the concept, it will not be messy anymore. Also if you do, helping you will be easier. Describing code is often laden with the misconceptions which cause it to malfunction. Making an MCVE provices a second layer of communication which usually helps spotting the root fo the problem.

Comment: The answer is too complex for  Q/A format unless you are a little more specific.  The layout of the mdat is described in the moov (or moof) you can’t address one without addressing the other.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

H.264 can be in different stream formats. One is called "Annex B" the other one is MP4.
In "Annex B" your NAL units are prefix with start codes 00 00 00 01 or 00 00 01.
In MP4 your NAL units are prefixed with the size in bytes.

I assume your encoder emits "Annex B".

1. Remove the start code (00) 00 00 01
2. Prefix your NAL units with the size (typically 4 bytes)
3. Filter out AUD/SPS/PPS NAL units from your stream
4. Write you converted NAL units into the MDAT box
5. Create an AVC Configuration Box ('avcC') based on your SPS, PPS and the length size
6. Store your avcC box in moov->trak->mdia->minf->stbl->avc1->avcC
7. While you are writing your samples into mdat - keep track of sizes, offsets and frame types to create the correct stts, stss, stsc, stsz and stco boxes.

Comment: You said "I assume your encoder emits "Annex B", but you are removing the start code. Maybe you meant "MP4" instead of "Annex B"?

Comment: No - I meant Annex B and yes you are removing the start codes (00) 00 00 01 to convert from Annex B to MP4.

Comment: Ah, got it. You are converting it from Annex B to MP4. Reading your answer I was with the impression that you could have both types (Annex B or MP4) as MDAT, but you cannot, you need to convert it to MP4. Now it is clear. Thank you.